# How to use MPUT in PSFTP to put the file with permission 777?

Tags: linux, sftp, ftp

I don't want to use `chmod 777 *.xml` so how I can use MPUT to put the file with permission 777? Without using `chmod 777 *.xml` the default file permission becomes 0664.

This is my script

```
dir
lcd E:\Inbound
cd /interface/incoming
mput *.xml
chmod 777 *.xml
```

Comment: That is the `-u` option, according to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/70876/how-to-put-desired-umask-with-sftp)

Comment: @ThomasDickey That's a SFTP server-side option. Might be helpful if OP has admin access to the remote SFTP server, but it won't be applicable client-side.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not possible.

According to chapters 6.2.10 and 6.2.11 of [PuTTY PSFTP documentation](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/0.76/htmldoc/Chapter6.html#psftp-commands), there is no way to specify file permissions with the `put` or `mput` PSFTP commands.

The `umask` value used by the remote SFTP server determines which permissions the copied files will get. This might be the default `umask` value of the remote user account, or an explicitly configured `umask` value, if the server administrator has decided to override the default.

If you have admin access to the remote SFTP server, [see this question on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/q/70876/442837) for ways to specify default umask for SFTP transfers.

The administrator of the remote server might be able to set an ACL that overrides the default umask value in a specific directory, if the filesystem type used on the remote server supports ACLs.

Comment: Thanks for your share